# 99 BMW 323i E46 5 Speed Manual Trans Stuck In Reverse

Tags: bmw, manual-transmission

I drained the fluid and found metal pieces. It won't shift into any gear other than reverse. When I try to shift into the other gears it locks up and stalls out. Can anybody help I think I'll have to replace the gear box or is this a DIY project?

Comment: image of the metal pieces? Is the oil full in the transmission?